# PHP - переопределение метода абстрактного класса

Tags: php, ооп

Есть абстрактный класс с обычными методами, от которого наследуется много других классов, как можно не вносить изменение в сам абстрактный класс, переопределить или дополнить методы абстрактного класса, чтобы наследуемые классы этого абстрактного видели эти изменения ?

Comment: как бы сделать, но не делая?

Comment: Никак. Если далее от класса, в котором вы сделаете изменения, не идет наследования - то никак.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-method-add.php

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментариям выше (заряд голосования вышел на сегодня) и хочу добавить, что у вас проблемы с архитектурой, если вы задумались о подобной задаче на практике, а не с целью подтянуть теорию.

Comment: У меня проблем с архитектурой нет. Есть ядро CMS, в классе которого не предусмотрены события, которые необходимы. Вот и встал вопрос о переопределении метода класса ядра.